# Molecular genetics textbook (free?) suggestion for first time

Tags: molecular-genetics, book-recommendation

I have never taken a molecular genetics course but want to prime myself for graduate school in the future. Does anyone have any suggestions or advice? A professor recommends "the molecular biology of the gene - latest edition" but I dont have too much money to spend on a text and simply prefer free/digital formats. ( less to carry)

Comment: Molecular Biology of the Gene is an excellent text that your university library may have.

Comment: Buy textbooks. Go without a meal or three if necessary, but buy books!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can’t comment otherwise this would be a comment, not an answer, sorry...

If you can’t lay your hands on a cheap (legal) text book that is of quality and in digital format then  maybe check out course material from [MIT open courseware](https://ocw.mit.edu/high-school/biology/exam-prep/molecular-genetics/) or something similar. As a further alternative, you should be able to find decent pop science books which are applicable and may be more useful than you think. [The Epigenetics Revolution](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/12414734-the-epigenetics-revolution), for example, provided me with a really solid grounding when first trying get to grips with the subject.